# AdMob Ads in an endless RecyclerView with Paging library

Tags: android, admob, android-recyclerview, android-paging

I am using [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) to fetch data from server, I was thinking of showing Ad after every 10 items. So as the user scrolls down and new items are fetched and added to PagedList. I want the new Ad to be loaded and added in `RecyclerView` as well just like Instagram shows ads in feeds. So if the user scrolls to 200 items, 20 ads will be shown gradually!!. I have read a couple of tutorials but I haven't figured an easy way to do it.

Here is my adapter.

```
class RequestsPagedAdapter(
        private val retryCallback: () -> Unit, private val from: From)
    : PagedListAdapter<RequestsQuery.Request, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(POST_COMPARATOR) {
    private var networkState: NetworkState? = null

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            R.layout.z_request_item -> (holder as RequestViewHolder).bind(getItem(position)!!, from)
            R.layout.network_state_item -> (holder as NetworkStateItemViewHolder).bindTo(networkState)
            R.layout.ad_admob_banner -> (holder as AdMobViewHolder)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
            holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            position: Int,
            payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
        if (payloads.isNotEmpty()) {
            val item = getItem(position)
            (holder as RequestViewHolder).updateProduct(item!!)
        } else {
            onBindViewHolder(holder, position)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            R.layout.z_request_item -> RequestViewHolder.create(parent)
            R.layout.network_state_item -> NetworkStateItemViewHolder.create(parent, retryCallback)
            R.layout.ad_admob_banner -> AdMobViewHolder.create(parent)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown view type $viewType")
        }
    }

    private fun hasExtraRow() = networkState != null && networkState != NetworkState.LOADED

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when {
            hasExtraRow() && position == itemCount - 1 -> R.layout.network_state_item
            position % ITEMS_PER_AD == 0 + 2 -> R.layout.ad_admob_banner
            else -> R.layout.z_request_item
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return super.getItemCount() + if (hasExtraRow()) 1 else 0
    }

    fun setNetworkState(newNetworkState: NetworkState?) {
        val previousState = this.networkState
        val hadExtraRow = hasExtraRow()
        this.networkState = newNetworkState
        val hasExtraRow = hasExtraRow()
        if (hadExtraRow != hasExtraRow) {
            if (hadExtraRow) {
                notifyItemRemoved(super.getItemCount())
            } else {
                notifyItemInserted(super.getItemCount())
            }
        } else if (hasExtraRow && previousState != newNetworkState) {
            notifyItemChanged(itemCount - 1)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val POST_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RequestsQuery.Request>() {
            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: RequestsQuery.Request, newItem: RequestsQuery.Request): Boolean =
                    oldItem == newItem

            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: RequestsQuery.Request, newItem: RequestsQuery.Request): Boolean =
                    oldItem.id() == newItem.id()
        }
    }
}
```

This is how data is submitted to `PagedList` from `Fragment`.

```
private fun getRequests() {
    subcategoryRequestsListViewModel.requests.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        adapter.submitList(it)
    })
    subcategoryRequestsListViewModel.networkState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        adapter.setNetworkState(it)
    })
}
```

And `ViewHolder`

```
class AdMobViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    companion object {
        fun create(parent: ViewGroup): AdMobViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.ad_admob_banner, parent, false)
            return AdMobViewHolder(view)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which part of it do you need help with? The part of getting the correct index to show it? or the displaying the ad part?

Comment: @SoftwarePerson I think every part. In normal recyclerView its easy because you know number of items you have so you know number of ads to request too, But in paged I its differenent

Answer (score 2):

There can not be an easy example of it than [google example here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/java/advanced/BannerRecyclerViewExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/bannerrecyclerviewexample)
The only difference is that it takes it data from XML file saved in raw and you take your data from elsewhere. I hope you can easily modify this example according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a list of ads in the adapter like this:

```
    private val nativeAds = mutableListOf<UnifiedNativeAd>()
```

Then your `onBindViewHolder` will look like this:

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<Any>, position: Int) {
    when (getItemViewType(position)) {
        NATIVE_AD -> {
            val adPosition = position * nativeAds.size / itemCount
            val nativeAd = nativeAds[adPosition]
            holder.performBind(nativeAd)
        }
        else ->  holder.performBind(getItem(position))
    }

}
```

Your `getItemViewType` like this:

```
 override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val nativeAdRows = getNativeAdRows()
   return if(hasNativeAds() && nativeAdRows.contains(position)){
        NATIVE_AD
    }else {
       //get other model item
   }
}
```

The remaining parts of the code:

```
fun onNativeAdLoaded() {
    val rows = getNativeAdRows()
    Timber.d("Native Ad Rows: $rows")
    Timber.d("Total items: $itemCount")
    rows.forEach {
        notifyItemInserted(it)
    }
}

private fun hasNativeAds(): Boolean {
    return nativeAds.isNotEmpty()
}

private fun getNativeAdRows(): List<Int>{
    val rows = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (i in 0 .. itemCount){
        if(i != 0 && i % Config.NATIVE_AD_AFTER_POSTS == 0){
            rows.add(i)
        }
    }
    return rows
}
```

Check this gist for [sample code](https://gist.github.com/KryptKode/d6bd03badacd7322318367e6c75ebad8)

Answer (score 1):

the first step must be declared a field in the adapter like blew

```
private val ADS_ITEM = 0
private val NORMAL_ITEM = 1
```

so, the next step you must create two type instance viewHolder

```
inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var title: TextView = itemView.item_text

}

inner class AdsMyViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var title: TextView = itemView.item_text
}
```

and create a new instance suitable viewHolder

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    return if (viewType == NORMAL_ITEM) {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        vh = MyViewHolder(v)
        vh as MyViewHolder
    } else {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ads, parent, false)
        vh = AdsMyViewHolder(v)
        vh as AdsMyViewHolder
    }
}
```

don't forget override getItemViewType

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return when (getItems()[position]) {
        is AdsSampleModel -> ADS_ITEM
        else -> NORMAL_ITEM
    }
}
```

last step bind item with suitable data

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when (holder) {
        is MyViewHolder -> {
            vh = holder
            val model = getItems()[position] as SampleModel
            (vh as MyViewHolder).title.text = model.getId().toString()
        }
        else -> {
            vh = holder
            val model = getItems()[position] as AdsSampleModel
            (vh as AdsMyViewHolder).title.text = model.getText()
        }
    }
}
```

add new item after paging

```
fun view () {
    endless = object : EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager) {
        fun onLoadMore(page: Int, totalItemsCount: Int, view: RecyclerView) {
            getNext()
        }
    }
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(endless)
}


fun getNext() {
    if (hasNextPage) {
        page++
        val callBack = object : YourCallback {
            override fun onSuccess(response: ResponseValue?) {
                if (response!!.getList().size() == 0)
                    hasNextPage = false
                else
                    addData(response!!.getList())
            }
            override fun onError() {
                // error handling
            }
        }
    }
}


private fun addData(models: List<YourModel>?) {
    for (i in models?.indices) {
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            list.add(ADS_TYPE)
        }
    }

    // notify adapter must be doing by main thread
    runOnUiThread { adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() }
}
```